# Can Druids use Sylvan to speak with animals without using the spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, druid

In order for Druids to speak to animals (deer, owls, lions, etc.), are they required to use Speak With Animals **spell**, or would speaking Sylvan also accommodate this?

Or does Sylvan only apply to magical beasts and Fey? Or perhaps up to the DM on how it works? Just a general idea would help, a friend of mine is playing her first druid & asked.

I am a little confused with this, thanks ahead of time :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Animals don’t speak any language; Sylvan is the language of Fey. Most magical beasts don’t speak any language either, but those who do will have that language noted in their entry (and it may not be Sylvan).

*Speak with animals* or similar magical powers are the only way to communicate with creatures that do not have a language.

A DM, of course, is free to change these things, but your setting would be very, very different from the real world if all animals were capable of speech (and, for that matter, they somehow all spoke the same language).